# Is It Bad for SEO to Have Multiple Domain Names If You Set Up rel="alternate" Tags Correctly?

Tags: seo, multiple-domains, rel

We have several sites that have multiple domain names. Rather than forwarding to one domain name, we set up `rel="alternate"` tags in the header of each page, pointing to the other versions of that page, with one page marked as `rel="canonical"`.

I was under the impression that this would allow spiders to correctly determine that the pages are not content spamming. However, a client has had a report from a "SEO Expert" who cclaims the opposite.

If the `rel="alternate"` tages are set up correctly, is there a problem?

Answer (score 3):

You're using the wrong tags. You should be using `rel="canonical` on all of the domains that are not the primary domain. `rel="alternate"` does **not** tell search engines that a secondary domain is canonical to a primary domain.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have something like this:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://mainsite.com/page.html" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://othersite.com/page.html" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://yetanothersite.com/page.html" />
```

in the `head` section of each of `mainsite.com/page.html`, `othersite.com/page.html` and `yetanothersite.com/page.html` (possibly excluding any self-links).

If so, that should be fine: all your duplicate pages have a `rel="canonical"` link pointing to a single canonical URL, so that's the URL that search engines will index.

As far as I know, Google at least doesn't currently pay any attention to the `rel="alternate"` links when used like this.  (They [do use them for finding translated versions of pages](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=189077), but only if you specify the appropriate `hreflang` attribute.)  So you could just leave them out and save a few bytes that way.  On the other hand, having them there shouldn't hurt, either, at least when [used appropriately](http://microformats.org/wiki/rel-alternate).